# Creating http echo server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, echo, response

What I need to do is simple node.js http echo server. However, servers that I found on node website and on some other places either don't work how I would like or I don't understand how they work.

I used this simple echo server and on my client side (written in java) I don't get the results I would want to.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request,response){

 response.writeHead(200);
 request.pipe(response);

}).listen(8080);
```

I would like my server to make a response consisting of response header and response body where I would have the whole http request that my client sent and got back. Client side is measuring time from sending a request and getting a whole response back. Client is also writing a response body to a file.

When I try using something like

```
 response.write(request.url);
```

I get the request.url in the response body and it works but I would like to have the whole http request inside.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Node.js Guide shows how to do this https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(request.headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `response.end()` when done:

```js
http.createServer(function(request,response){

  response.writeHead(200)
  request.pipe(response)
  response.end()

}).listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample echo server that also logs the request method, url, headers, and body in addition to echoing the body back as well as provides the necessary CORS configuration to handle preflight OPTION requests properly.

### Server

```js
const http = require("http");
const port = 8080;

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const headers = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age": 2592000, // 30 days
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      /** add other headers as per requirement */
    };

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.writeHead(204, headers);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (["GET", "POST", "PUT"].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      let body = [];
      req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(`==== ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    console.log('> Headers');
        console.log(req.headers);

    console.log('> Body');
    console.log(body);

        res.write(body);
        res.end();
      });
      // res.end("Hello World");
      return;
    }

    res.writeHead(405, headers);
    res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
  })
  .listen(port);
console.log("listening on port " + port);
```

### Example Usage

```bash
curl -X PUT -d '{"message": "hello"}' localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

http is tcp, so make a tcp server and echo

```js
const net = require('node:net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    console.clear(); // I like this
    socket.on(`data`, d => {
        socket.write(d);
        console.log(String(d));
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.end();
    }, 100);
}).on('error', (err) => {
    throw err;
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`opened server on ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

well you are trying to pipe the request to the response which doesn't make sense and doesn't work. I'd advice you to use the `connect` or `express` module. Then you can do this; `response.status(200).send("Very Awesome").end()`.